# Linking a new Wordpress theme / site to an old Wordpress theme / site while maintaining new site nav?

Tags: php, wordpress

here's my dilemna:

I created a website using a specific theme (I'll call it Theme A) for an annual event in my community (I'll call it Event A 2014).  Now, I've begun a redesign of the site for this year's new event (Event B 2015) using another Wordpress theme (Theme B).  Right now I have a navbar on my Event B 2015 Theme B site with two year list items ("2015" and "2014").  The site for Event A 2014 Theme A has multiple pages; it is finished.  What I'm trying to do is, **when a user clicks on the "2014" navbar list item it redirects them to the full Event A 2014 Theme A site while maintaining the new Event B 2015 Theme B navbar so that they can easily hop between years / Themes**.  Is this possible?  I have full admin and FTP access to each site's file directory.  Right now the Event B 2015 Theme B site is in a sandbox but will eventually be moved to the domain that Event A 2014 Theme A has right now, once launched.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the multi-site concept of Wordpress

Comment: I have one domain finished right now, I'm trying to merge another theme from a sandbox with this doman, but only for the home page, linking the entire old site with menus and everything when the user clicks "2014", but while maintaining the "2015" navbar on top with a link back to the "2015" site / new theme if the user wants to hop to this year ... is this multi-site?  I already have one instance installed and set, can I do this without making completely new installation(s) of Wordpress?

Comment: Yes by implementing WordPress multisite network, you can create multiple instances only with single WordPress installation.